# Can't configure Scala in Intellij IDEA 13

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I entered Scala courses on Coursera and used to write Scala projects in `Eclipse Indigo`. All worked well. But now I gonna to convert to my favorite IDE - Intellij IDEA.

But I can't configure it for Scala usage.

***What I've already done:***

1. Install Scala, set system `SCALA_HOME` variable
2. Install SBT
3. Install Scala plugin on Intellij IDEA

***What a problem:***

1. When I import coursera assignments, Intellij doesn't see some classes like `List`, `Array` etc. For example, when I try to import it via `Alt+Enter` key it propose me `java.jang.reflect.Array`, `java.sql.Array`, `com.sun.xml....Array`. So I can't import Scala Array with `tail` and `head` methods.
2. When I try: `New Project` -> `Scala Module` the are to problems:

   a) When I choose `Set Scala Home` it complains that there are missing files

   b) When I choose `Existent Library` there is nothing to choose in `Compiler`/`Standart` fields.

[image]

***Question:***

How to configure Intellij properly?

Comment: SBT built-in support is recent, I had issues with it in some projects. I would recommend you try https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea for while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is the directory you specified the right one?  It should have bin, doc, etc. in it.  If so, try entering the following by hand:

For compiler library, `scala-compiler`

For standard library, `scala-library`

IDEA found these for me automatically, but perhaps something went wrong for you.

Comment: how about already existed project? When I import a project idea doesn't see scala classes.

Comment: I've never been able to find that same form with an existing project.  I think it may have something to do with the external build.  You may be able to get it to work by adding a new library with scala-compiler.jar and scala-library.jar.

Answer (score 9):

It can be a problem with caches, try File -> Invalidate Caches

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to manually add the `scala-library` as a dependency to your module. 
This is not done automatically when adding the Scala facet to an existing module.